# Is it “rather than letting” or ”let”?

Tags: gerunds, bare-infinitives, let

I saw a question on an exercise book that read

> When someone is criticizing you, you can try to handle the criticism in a positive and productive way to improve yourself rather than ____ it lower your self-esteem.

Someone had written "letting", and it was marked incorrect. The answer turned out to be "let", but couldn't "letting" be an answer? Also, could I say "marked wrong" or "marked incorrect"?

Answer (score 2):

"Letting" is correct, and I slightly prefer it to "let".

"Marked wrong" or "Marked incorrect" both are good.

Answer (score 1):

From the grammar section in *Cambridge Dictionary* the quoted excerpt helps explain why the bare infinite version was the *preferred* answer in the OP's exercise. It does not mean "…*rather than letting* it lower your self-esteem." is wrong, both forms are acceptable.

However, CD suggests that **the gerund form is less common.** I don't know how true this is but the [Cambridge English Corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambridge_English_Corpus) is well known and respected worldwide. It contains *billions* of words taken from a variety of English dialects such as British and American. The data is regularly updated, and reflects both spoken and written English.

> We use *[rather than](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/rather?q=rather%20than)* to give more importance to one thing when two alternatives or preferences are being compared:
>
> - He wanted to be an actor **rather than** a comedian.
> - Can we come over on Saturday **rather than** Friday?
>
> *Rather than* usually occurs between two things which are being compared. However, we can also use it at the beginning of a sentence. When we use *rather than* with a verb, we use the base form or (less commonly) the -ing form of a verb:
>
> **Rather than pay** the taxi fare, he walked home.
>      (or **Rather than paying** the taxi fare, he walked home.)

Both "marked wrong" and "marked incorrect" are interchangeable and idiomatic in English.